# Hue UI Sqoop through Oozie - Passing Parameter values

Tags: cloudera, sqoop, oozie, hue

I am trying to pass the server details and username and password thorugh job.properties files in **Sqoop action in HUE Oozie**.

**we are on sqoop 1.4.5-cdh5.3.3**

If i run this command on CLI this runs fine, but on Hue Oozie workflow it fails

Command in sqoop action UI:

```
list-databases --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://${dbserver}:140" --      username=edm_hadoop_user --password=${dbpass}
```

Scenario:

I have the **job.properties** files which has the below info in it and it is present along with workflow.xml file in HDFS.

```
dbserver=FACETS
   dbport=140
   dbuser=*******
   dbpass=*******
```

1. if i populate "Parms" and test this with values to 'dbserver' and 'dbpass' it works fine, which i dont want to do it since i need to schedule this workflow and want it to run automatically by picking up the server and password details from a file
2. if i add "Job properties" like this

   property name = dbserver value=${dbserver} 
   and like wise for dbpass as well it fails with error cannot resolve dbserver which means its not sustituting the values from job.properties file.
3. if i add "Files" and specify the job.properties file location in it its not picking up the values either and the job fails.

I have also created a job.xml file with above values in it as properties and gave that file name in "Job XML" even then the workflow failed.

How should i specify the parameters if i want to run sqoop action workflow from Hue UI oozie ?

Or should i be doing this by creating workflow.xml and job.properties file separately and call them using shell action on Oozie Hue ?